# how to create paginator with increments of 5 pages in django

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-templates

I have the following paginator template code:

```
{% if my_paginator.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
        <div class="more_results">
        {% if my_paginator.has_previous %}
            <a href="?{% if query %}?q={{ query }}&amp;{% endif %}page={% if my_paginator.has_previous %}{{ my_paginator.previous_page_number }}{% else %}1{% endif %}">&laquo; previous</a>
        {% endif %}
                    {% for x in my_paginator.paginator.page_range|slice:":10" %}
                <a href="?{% if query %}?q={{ query }}&amp;{% endif %}page={{ x }}{% if fromdate != '' %}&from={{fromdate}}{% endif %}{% if todate != '' %}&to={{todate}}{% endif %}"><u>{{ x }}</u></a> 

                    {% endfor %}
        {% if my_paginator.has_next %}
                <a href="?{% if query %}?q={{ query }}&amp;{% endif %}page={% if my_paginator.has_next %}{{ my_paginator.next_page_number }}{% else %}{{ my_paginator.paginator.count }}{% endif %}">next &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
       </div>
{% endif %}
```

The problem is that when there are 100 pages of results having a 100 page links looks ridiculous. It looks like this:

> < Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 (to 100) Next >

I would like to show increments of the latest 10 page results.

Something like this:

> < Previous 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15 Next >

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe let us know what the problem with the version you posted is?

Comment: @BernhardVallant ok I showed an example of the problem output